# Search Bar Left Image Tint Change iOS for Dark Mode

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, placeholder, darkmode

Trying to get the left most image icon within the search bar to change color for Dark Mode in iOS 13

Ive tried making a call directly to the searchBar and changing its background color, changing the text color, and finally I've tried a couple different iterations of the code below.

```
        searchBar.backgroundColor = .clear
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "magnifyingglass")
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            searchBar.textField?.attributedPlaceholder = 
    NSAttributedString(string: (" " + NSLocalizedString("search_actions", comment: "")), 
    attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.separator, 
    NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor: UIColor.separator])
            
        }
```

Comment: What the question?  Why only iOS 13?

Comment: iOS 13 or newer, because iOS 13 is when dark mode was released @meaning-matters